# How can I get certain rows and the "previous" rows from a table that includes a datetime column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, query-optimization

I have two tables, Alpha & Bravo. Bravo has a column `id` (integer, primary key) and some other columns that are not relevant for this question. Alpha has columns `id` (integer, primary key), `bravo_id` (foreign key to table Bravo), `special` (a single char, null for most rows but has a value for certain important rows), `created` (a DATETIME), and some others not relevant to this question.

I would like to get all the special rows from Alpha, *plus* for each special row I would like to get the "previous" non-special row from Alpha associated with the same row of Beta (that is, I would like to get the Alpha row with the same `bravo_id` and the most recent `created` that is older than the `created` of the special row), and I need to keep the special row & its previous row linked.

Currently I'm doing this with n+1 queries:

```
SELECT id, bravo_id, created FROM Alpha WHERE special IS NOT NULL
```

followed by a query like this for each result in the initial query:

```
SELECT id, created FROM Alpha
WHERE special IS NULL AND bravo_id = BrvN AND created < CrtN ORDER BY created DESC
```

Obviously that's wildly inefficient. Is there a way I can retrieve this information in a single query that will put each special row & its previous non-special row in a single row of the result?

Our product supports both SQL Server (2008 R2 if relevant) and Oracle (11g if relevant) so a query that works for both of those would be ideal, but a query for only one of the two would be fine.

**EDIT:** "Created" is perhaps a misnomer. The datetime in that column is when the referenced object was created, and *not* when it was entered into the database (which could be anywhere from seconds to years later). An ordering of the rows of Alpha based on the `created` column would have little or no correlation to an ordering based on the `id` column (which is a traditional incrementing identity/sequence).

Comment: In Oracle (or SQL Server 2012) you can use the `lag()` function to get values from the "previous" row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in both SQL Server & Oracle:

```
select A.id, A.bravo_id, A.created, B.id, B.created
from Alpha A
left join Alpha B on A.bravo_id = B.bravo_id
                 and B.created < A.created
                 and B.special is null
where A.special is not null
  and (B.created is null or
       B.created = (select max(S.created)
                    from Alpha S
                    where S.special is null
                      and S.bravo_id = A.bravo_id
                      and S.created < A.created))
```

It left joins in all rows with the same foreign key and a lower/older created, then uses the where clause to filter them out (being careful not to exclude A rows that have no older row).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Bravo_Id, a.Created, d.Id, d.Created FROM @Alpha a
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 da.id, da.Created 
    FROM @Alpha da
    WHERE da.Special IS NULL
        AND da.Bravo_Id = a.Bravo_Id
        AND da.Created < a.Created
    ORDER BY da.Created DESC
) d
WHERE a.Special IS NOT NULL
```

You can bind both queries with apply (ms sql server query)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server 2008 doesn't support cumulative sum.  Here is an approach to solving the problem.

For each row in Alpha, count the number of special rows *after* alpha.  This will assign a grouping.  Within the group, then use `row_number()` to enumerate the values, and choose the first two.

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by bravo, grp order by id desc) as seqnum
      from (select a.*,
                   (select count(*)
                    from alpha a2
                    where a2.bravo = a.bravo and a2.special = 1 and
                          a2.id >= a.id
                   ) as grp
            from alpha a
           ) a
     ) a
where seqnum <= 2;
```

In Oracle (or SQL Server 2012), you would write this as:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by bravo, grp order by id desc) as seqnum
      from (select a.*,
                   sum(case when special = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by bravo order by id desc
                   ) as grp
            from alpha a
           ) a
     ) a
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: This seems like it has potential, but I realized I didn't properly explain the use of the `created` column. Please see my edit to the original question and check if your answer needs to be adjusted.